# Content Security Policy causing CORS errors

Tags: .htaccess, content-security-policy, http-referer

weird one but the referer policy is currently creating issues on my website if the domain has a . on the end, for example:
`domain.uk` - works fine
`domain.uk.` - has CORS errors
It seems the `.` on the end os being treated as part of the domain so considered a different origin. Seems to only be a problem in Chrome. Possibly a Chrome bug?

Thought perhaps I could fix this in my .htaccess by setting up a redirect, but the .htaccess cannot do it as it can only match after the domain, and the `.` is being treated as part of the domain.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

> It seems the `.` on the end os being treated as part of the domain so considered a different origin. Seems to only be a problem in Chrome. Possibly a Chrome bug?

It *is* part of the domain. The trailing dot indicates a [fully qualified domain name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name). If you are only seeing different behaviour in Chrome then maybe Chrome is just being more strict - it's not a bug.

Try `https://stackoverflow.com./` (for instance) - you'll probably appear logged out (as the cookies are not passed).

> Thought perhaps I could fix this in my `.htaccess` by setting up a redirect, but the .htaccess cannot do it as it can only match after the domain, and the `.` is being treated as part of the domain.

You can do it in `.htaccess`. The dot is sent as part of the `Host` header (since it is part of the domain) - which is available in the `HTTP_HOST` server variable. Ordinarily, you'd do this as part of your canonical (www vs non-www / HTTP to HTTPS) redirect, but you could do something like the following using mod_rewrite to remove the trailing dot on the requested hostname:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.+)\.$
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

The `%1` backreference contains the hostname, less the trailing dot, that is captured in the preceding *condition*.

**UPDATE:**

> I am using Wordpress so it already has some rewrite rules in the htaccess, ... can you advise on how to add your rewrites

You need to place this redirect *before* the existing WordPress directives (ie. *before* the `# BEGIN WordPress` section), near the top of the file.

You do not need to repeat the `RewriteEngine On` directive since that already occurs later in the WordPress section. (If there are multiple `RewriteEngine` directives then the *last* instance wins and controls the entire file.)

Comment: That all makes sense, however I am using Wordpress so it already has some rewrite rules in the htaccess, forgive my ignorance but can you advise on how to add your rewrites to my existing:
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

Comment: @MikeOram You need to place this redirect _before_ the existing WordPress directives (_before_ the `# BEGIN WordPress` section), near the top of the file. You do not need to repeat the `RewriteEngine On` directive, since that already occurs later in the WordPress section. (If there are multiple `RewriteEngine` directives then the _last_ instance wins and controls the entire file.)